# Laravel select menu to show selected from DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

How can i get a dropdown to select whatever id is present within the database.

I have a user's table that has a location_id and a towns table that has town_id and town_name so I want the dropdown to know what the user table location_id is and show the town_name based on the id.

How can this be done in Laravel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone willing to help a Laravel newbie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would do is assign your user and towns to the view. Next loop your towns table to generate your select list. Something like:

```
<select name="location">
  @foreach($towns as $town)
    <option value="{{ $town->id }}" {{ ($user->location_id == $town_id) ? "selected" : "" }}>{{ $town->town_name }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Cheers Eric I'll check that out

Comment: I'm getting syntax error, unexpected '?' 

on <?php if ($user->location == $town_id) ? "selected" : ""><?php echo $town->town ?>

Comment: Bah ternary fail. :) <?php ($user->location == $town_id) ? "selected" : ""?>

Comment: No it's beacuse Im using Blade rather then just a .php file

Comment: Updated the sample for blade

Comment: Ok tried what you've put and I have got this in my controller

$towns = DB::table('towns')->lists('town','town_id');

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it to match blade:

```
    <select name="location" class="form-control">
             @ foreach($towns as $town)
               <option value="{{ $town->town_id}}"  @if ($user->location == $town->town_id) "selected" @else "" @endif>{{ $town->town }}</option>
             @endforeach
           </select>
```

But it's not showing the selected item

Comment: What yo are sending from the controller ? How your tables are related to each other ?

Comment: Is this only about repopulating the selected item when redirected to back ?

Comment: $towns = DB::table('towns')->lists('town','town_id'); is wht i have in controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending correct data to the view and the problem is only repopulating the select then you may try this, just put this in your view and send `$towns` from your controller as you are sending now

```
{{ Form::select('towns', $towns, Input::old('towns')) }}
```

No need to manually loop through the array. Laravel's [Form](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists) class will build the select/dropdown.

Comment: Yes but i'm wanting it to select the id from the db so its shows the lives in New York for example and not show the first in the list

Comment: Your question is not clear, try to rephrase it please. How your both tables are constructed ? post their fields and relationship if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

My last answer works, just find it was cached by the looks in the browser, so all fixed.